# Spring boot 2.1.1, use postgres config with jpa

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I build some simple spring boot project, with jpa/postgres.

But when i debug this project, error say

> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
>
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

But in my application.properties that have url.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/oauth?currentSchema=oauth
spring.datasource.username=SOME_USER_NAME
spring.datasource.password=SOME_PASSWORD
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

#hibernate
spring.jpa.database = postgresql
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Does anyone know about this?

if validation is trouble than debug don't say like 'url attribute is not specified'.

And My application.properties name 'application-test.properties', and in debug configuration set 'test', and also log say 'the profiles test are currently active'.

It looks like properties is not matching, but log said profile is matched.

It makes me very confuse..

Comment: Can you share some repo related on this?

Comment: You have de postgres dependency in your pom.xml ? why you need spring.jpa.database in you application.properties ?

Comment: Oh it's gradle project and i import postgres like this.
When spring boot set up, I select postgres than build.gradle like this
`runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem. Jonathan Johx and TinyOS is right, Thanks for them.

If project built by spring boot 2.1.1, Intellij with postgres, then Override build.gradle and pom.xml.

In Spring-boot 2.1.1 (I still don't know why default value is it)

default setting is

```
runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
```

but If you want to run right, than must write 'compile' like this.

```
compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.5'
```

version is not important. just find in maven repo what you want version.